# One of my usb ports stoped working when i pluged laptop cooler

Tags: usb, 22.04, suspend, overheating

So I use 2-3 days laptop cooler and then I went to work. When I opened my laptop case laptop was burning, I power off my laptop. When laptop was cooled down I started again and there was no problem, I didn't notice one of my USB ports didn't work. So like 3 days later I tried to plug in my mouse but mouse didn't work, when I changed ports, it worked! When I do this with my working USB same. That USB has a light. USB light was working when I plug working port. So I restarted my laptop like 5 times but before that I couldn't suspend my computer when I tried it I got that error:
`usb usb3: PM dpm_run callback(): usb_dev suspend+0x0/0x20 returns -16` and then I forced to not suspend that and my computer suspended.

Then I tried to restart my computer than this error shows up

`usb3-port2: over-current condition`

`usb4-port2: over-current condition`

Ubuntu version: 22.04.2 LTS
Device Model: Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ARH05
GPU Model :NVDIA RTX1650

What should I do? Is my USB port dead?

There is also another question, after my computer overheated when I use normally (like I use vivaldi, I open like 3-4 tabs) average heat is showing 41 C degrees, max heat is 58 C degrees. Is that normal?

Comment: I forget to tell something, I used normally when I first pluged laptop cooler. It didn't stoped or something like that